# Design issue in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with android studio. i made the size and color of my textview in android studio as i wanted.The preview in it was fine but when i ran it on my device the size and color changed.what should i do?

the xml part is given below my actual out put was textview with default size and color

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fontFamily="cursive"
android:text="City Scanner"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
tools:textAlignment="center"
tools:textColor="@color/colorText"
tools:textSize="50sp"/>
```

[see the size and color of text view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hns1Y.png)

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), and  [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that you should do is to check your layout on different screen sizes before loading the app on your physical device. You can change the screen size as indicated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5NED.png).

For more detail about supporting different screen sizes, read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes).

[image]

Comment: I have checked it all. I don't think that is the problem